# How to create a copy of table that is in-memory optimized?

Tags: sql, sql-server, in-memory-database, memory-optimized-tables

I have a table `T1` that I created in-memory using the in-memory procedure in SQL Server 2016. Now, I want to create a copy of the same table `T1` into another table `T2` which should have the same schema i.e it should also be in-memory(should be memory optimized).

I know that for creating a copy of a table we use the following query:

```
SELECT * INTO T2 FROM T1
```

But when I use the above query, it creates a blank table `T2` which is not in-memory i.e not memory optimized.
So, How do I create a copy of an existing in-memory table with the same schema and if possible same data.

Comment: Take a look at the following link, it might be useful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Are you suggesting to use temp table variable?

Comment: could explain more about the scenario and provide sample code of your tables?